# CCodeGenerate and calling external functions

Tags: external-calls, code-generation

Is it possible to use `CCodeGenerate` to generate code which calls functions from other C libraries? For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
CCodeGenerate[Compile[{{x}}, f[x]+1], "f1"]
```

where `f` is a function defined in some other library (which I would then link to the generated code). I tried to first make `f` available in *Mathematica* via LibraryLink, but then `CCodeGenerate` issues a warning (`CCodeGenerate::wmreq`) and returns `$Failed`.

Comment: According to Wolfram support "Calling functions from external C libraries is currently not supported by CCodeGenerate. It only supports creation of libraries from the code generated using LibraryGenerate function." I find this rather disappointing.