# Unexpected behavior: CForm converts rationals to floating numbers

Tags: output-formatting

**One line question:** How to make `CForm[1/2]` generate `1/2` instead of `0.5`? (Thanks Nasser's comment!)

---

I've been using `CForm` to convert *Mathematica* expressions to C codes for a long time. Although the built-in C strings are a little bit annoying (e.g., `Sqrt[2]` is translated to "Sqrt(2)" instead of "sqrt(2)"), it works.

However, recently I found an even more annoying behavior which I cannot find a workaround so far. Consider converting the following simple piece extracted from a rather complicated expression

```
3/40007 + (2 test )/40007//CForm
```

> 0.00007498687729647311 + (2*test)/40007.

which is totally bizarre! What I expect is simply

> 3/40007. + (2*test)/40007.

which is trivial yet crucial to my following work. (To be clear, I don't mean the presence of the decimal point is crucial! Rather, I mean the form of numbers should no be changed.) Can anyone come up with a solution, at least to tell `CForm` stop doing such a floating number conversion? Certainly I could manually rewrite this piece (or use `Together`) like this

```
(3 + 2 test)/40007 // CForm
```

> (3 + 2*test)/40007.

But given that I have tons of complicated expressions to be converted, it is super inefficient for sure. Besides there's a possibility that `test = I`, and `3/40007 + (2 I)/40007 // Together` returns itself.

PS. It is surprising that the discussions related to `CForm` and other C utilities are so rare on this site! Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are asking _Mathematica_ to read your mind. We don't have the input by direct thought user interface yet, so you will have to write things like 3. and 40007. when they are critical to the interpretation you need.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I'm sorry but I have no idea what you're talking about...maybe you misunderstand my question?

Comment: Maybe I did, but I find it bizarre that you reject `0.00007498687729647311 + (2*test)/40007.`, which is what C would make of `3/40007. + (2 test )/40007.`

Comment: In short, I expect `CForm` to convert an Mathematica expression to a piece of C code (in the form of strings) without any pre-processing of the form of numbers, and this is how I used it in the past.

Comment: @m_goldberg, oh yes, I reject it for some accuracy and efficiency concerns...I may be wrong about it, but I think it would be better to keep `3/40007.` instead of `0.00007498687729647311`, at least that's what I expect `CForm` to do.

Comment: If this is a change in behavior between _Mathematica_ versions, I say take it up with WRI.

Comment: Oh, I meant I didn't have to convert rational additions like `3/40007 + (2 test )/40007` in the past, so `CForm` worked OK to me. I actually don't know how it behaves in different MMA versions. Currently I'm using MMA8 if someone would like to know.

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks for editing the tag btw.

Comment: Fantastic one line question @Nasser! I really should train myself harder to attack the critical point directly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Warning:** The conversion below can lead to wrong results in the C-code. Be aware of that.

Since you complain anyway about `"Sqrt"` and `"Pow"` have you considered writing your own `cform`? The real `CForm` seems a bit stubborn about the numerical evaluation of rational expressions and with your own version you can cure this too. A very basic hack could look like

```
cform[Rational[a_, b_]] := "(" <> cform[a] <> "/" <> cform[b] <> ")";
cform[Power[a_, b_]] := "pow(" <> cform[a] <> "," <> cform[b] <> ")";
cform[Sqrt[a_]] := "sqrt(" <> cform[a] <> ")";
cform[Plus[a_, b_]] := "(" <> cform[a] <> " + " <> cform[b] <> ")";
cform[Times[a_, b_]] := "(" <> cform[a] <> " * " <> cform[b] <> ")";
cform[a_?AtomQ] := ToString[a];
```

and then you go

```
3/40007 + (2 test)/40007 // cform
(* "((3/40007) + ((2/40007) * test))" *)
```

or even

```
Series[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}] // Normal // cform
(*
  (x + (((-1/6) * pow(x,3)) + (((1 + ((-1/2) * pow(x,2))) * y) + 
  (((((-1/2) * x) + ((1/12) * pow(x,3))) * pow(y,2)) + (((-1/6) + 
  ((1/12) * pow(x,2))) * pow(y,3))))))
*)
```

Maybe you can upload a larger expression to [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) so that we have a better feeling, what kinds of expressions you try to convert.

### Update to your comment

There are at least two thing you could make easier for yourself. First is, that all functions which are real function calls in C too, like `cexp`, `sqrt`, `abs`, ... probably don't need all their own rule, because the only important thing is that the function names are converted. Then the arguments are just supplied separated by a comma in parenthesis. Therefore, you could create a *general* rule and then you have to provide the conversion of the function name only.

Additionally, for everything unmatched, you probably want to call `ToString[...,CForm]` to make it convert at least to something. Here is your version striped of the pow and exp rules and I added 4 rules at the end:

```
cform[Rational[a_, b_]] := cform[a] <> "/" <> cform[b] <> "."; 
cform[Complex[a_, b_]] := 
 "(" <> If[cform[a] == "0", "", cform[a]] <> "+" <> cform[b] <> "*I" <>
   ")"; cform[Times[a_, b_]] := 
 "(" <> cform[a] <> ")" <> " * " <> "(" <> cform[b] <> ")"; 
cform[Plus[a_, b_]] := cform[a] <> " + " <> cform[b];
cform[a_?AtomQ] := ToString[a];
cform[h_[args__]] := 
  cform[h] <> "(" <> StringJoin[Riffle[cform /@ {args}, ","]] <> ")";
cform[Power] = "pow";
cform[Exp] = "cexp";
cform[Sqrt] = "sqrt";
cform[allOther_] := ToString[allOther, CForm];
```

Comment: The conversion of rationals into floats seems particularly problematic since it actually violates the C specifciation. I never noticed this behavior before (never used `CForm`), but nothing much seems to have changed about it since at least version 5.2.

Comment: Hi halirutan Thanks for your answer. I did consider define my own `cform` before, but I gave up for some reasons. Anyway, I tried your `cform` with your examples but I got totally different [outputs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/59QML.png). I already used a fresh kernel to do that. Did I mess up something?

Comment: @LeoFang No, you didn't. I did. Actually, the order of the rules is important since `Rational` is an atom too. Try again.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I never used `CForm` too and this is really just a hack to get the desired output without thinking about the consequences. Something like `1/2` is quite dangerous because you divide two `int`. I'll have a look at this post tomorrow. Pretty early here and I haven't slept.

Comment: @halirutan, almost figured it out by myself with `trace` while you were editing :) Glad to know an entirely different workaround indeed exists! The only apparent drawback of this approach I could tell now is that it produces so many parentheses. Yet it works, yay! A little bit run down now, so let me do an extensive test and report the result tomorrow. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: `cform[Rational[a_, b_]] := cform[a] <> "/" <> cform[b] <> "."; cform[Complex[a_, b_]] := "(" <> If[cform[a] == "0", "", cform[a]] <> "+" <> cform[b] <> "*I" <> ")"; cform[Power[a_, b_]] := "pow(" <> cform[a] <> "," <> cform[b] <> ")"; cform[Exp[a_]] := "cexp(" <> cform[a] <> ")"; cform[Sqrt[a_]] := "sqrt(" <> cform[a] <> ")"; cform[Times[a_, b_]] := "(" <> cform[a] <> ")" <> " * " <> "(" <> cform[b] <> ")"; cform[Plus[a_, b_]] := cform[a] <> " + " <> cform[b]; cform[a_?AtomQ] := ToString[a];`

Comment: @halirutan, I tweaked your `cform` a little bit to overcome the problem of integer divided by integer (e.g., `1/2`), support complex numbers when complex.h is included and (seem to) produce less parentheses. What do you think?

Comment: @LeoFang I used your tweaks and gave some more information at the end of my answer.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I've rarely used `CForm` directly, but I have used `Splice` which essentially uses `CForm`. I didn't notice the behavior with `Rational` before, likely because I was using floats. (Testing a c++ version of WignerJ.)

Comment: @rcollyer, never realized there exists a `Splice` function before! I always copy and paste the generated C codes manually into .C/.h files...Do you think it is good to start a new question to ask about how to automatically pipe _Mathematica_ outputs to external C files? It is somehow related but not identical to [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28965/ccodegenerate-and-calling-external-functions), since I'm interested more in making my working flow more smoothy and efficient.

Comment: @LeoFang the docs for `Splice` are pretty good, there are a couple of subtleties, though. So, I'd recommend trying to something modest, and seeing how it goes. Then ask any questions that arise. Now integrating into it the overall workflow is a bit more interesting, but make rules should be straightforward to generate. I have running around here code for integrating [`mprep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/mprep.html) into [boost build](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/), but it has been a while since I touched it.

Comment: @halirutan, very nice update on `cform[h_[args__]] := cform[h] <> "(" <> StringJoin[Riffle[cform /@ {args}, ","]] <> ")";`! Your `cform` now works better than built-in `CForm` for me. I've accepted your answer unless somebody comes up a much more fascinating answer later on (which is unlikely...). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LeoFang oh, and as to not realizing that `Splice` exists, I saw an answer the other day with a function that has been in there since v1, and in my nearly 20 years of use of _Mathematica_ I've _never_ run across it. And, I used to dig through the docs to find interesting things.

Comment: @rcollyer, apparently I'm too young to know everything! An excellent excuse for darn graduate student :D Thanks for bringing boost build up to me btw.

Answer (score 1):

I would unprotect [`Rational`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rational) and use [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format):

```
Unprotect[Rational];
Format[Rational[a_, b_], CForm] := HoldForm[Divide[HoldForm[a], b]]
Protect[Rational];
```

Your examples:

```
1/2 //CForm
```

> 1/2.

```
3/40007 + (2 test )/40007 //CForm
```

> 3/40007. + (2*test)/40007.